# How to pass parameter to an API function?

Tags: syntax, wolfram-cloud, apifunction

I have a very simple question. I don't know how to pass multiple parameters to a web deployed `APIFunction`.

I created a function:

```
func = APIFunction[{"t" -> "Real", "y"->"Real"}, #t*#y &];
api = CloudDeploy[func, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

and Mathematica gave me the link to the webdeployed function. I know that I can pass a single parameter by just adding `?{Parameter}` to the url. But what do I have to do, to pass `t` and `y`?

I couldn't find it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use yourURL?t=1.1&y=3.2

Answer (score 2):

```
func = APIFunction[{"t" -> "Real", "y"->"Real"}, #t*#y &];
api = CloudDeploy[func, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

You don't need to access it via browser. There are functions for that:

```
URLExecute[api, {"t" -> 1, "y" -> 5}]
```

> ```
> 5.
> ```

But if you insist:

```
URLBuild[First@api, {"t" -> 1, "y" -> 5}] // Echo // SystemOpen
```

> >> https://www.wolframcloud.com/...........?**t=1&y=5**